# How to write gte filter for Learning Locker Aggregation API (Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators)

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb-query, xapi, learning-locker

I'm writing a request for LRS service. I need to get from there statements that were created in the range of some date.
The filters `gte` and `lte` are suitable for this. But the [documentation](https://learninglocker.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/106037259/Aggregation+API) (and [this](https://learninglocker.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/106168396/Connection+API)) does not say how exactly they should be written. Should I use `and` or write them inside the field:

```
"statement.timestamp": {
    "$gte": "2022-04-01T00:00:00Z", 
    "$lte": "2022-05-01T00:00:00:00Z"
}
```

I'm also getting confused with the parentheses. Some examples have `{}`, others have `[{}]`, others just `[]`.

I understand that this is a Mongo specificity.

Speaking of Mongo. In its [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/#mongodb-query-op.-gte) there is an example of *Syntax: `{ field: { $gte: value } } }`*, but I catch an error with it (*Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators*).

I did a test with this query: `pipeline=[{"$limit": 1}]`. Everything worked fine for me.

Now my query looks like this:

```
pipeline=[{
    "$match": {
        "statement.timestamp": {
            "$gte": "2022-04-01T00:00:00:00Z"
        },
    }, "$limit": 1
}]
```

And with it I catch an error (*Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators*).

I tried different combinations of brackets `{}` and `[]`, but I think my error lies in the query construction.

Thanks !

Comment: You could be comparing to string values to a date field. Make sure you are using datatypes consistently. Also, `$limit` should be an individual stage. See if [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wmIfOEEm7kX) helps with your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14732669/ray) from the comment helped a lot with finding a solution.

Quote:

> You could be comparing to string values to a date field. Make sure you are using datatypes consistently. Also, `$limit` should be an individual stage. See if [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wmIfOEEm7kX) helps with your case – [ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14732669/ray)

`$limit` really needs to be put into a separate staging.
Specifically in my case the 502 error started to be thrown, and it was due to the fact that there were no records in the database satisfying the filter. (Or some other reason). Nevertheless, the code worked successfully with this variant of the query and returned several records to me.

> 'pipeline=[{
> "$match": {
> "statement.timestamp": {
> "$gte": "2020-11-30T15:21:52.698Z",
> "$lte": "2020-12-30T15:21:52.698Z"
> }
> }
> }, {"$limit": 5}]'

Thanks !